# fill text inside rectangular box in svg using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am creating a project using java script. I am using `d3.js` in my project. My problem is I want to fit the text inside rectangular boxes.

here is my jsfiddle Url:

https://jsfiddle.net/dc7z28f5/2/

Comment: increasing the dy doesn't help? like this-> https://jsfiddle.net/dc7z28f5/3/

Comment: but the axis looks like wrong

Comment: you mean the x axis?

Comment: axis which connects countries

Comment: You could re-position that too https://jsfiddle.net/dc7z28f5/4/

Comment: I solved this...Thanks to all